# Bootstrap 4 Container Overlapping Previous Container

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I am having trouble where a container placed after another overlaps the previous container on mobile. Specifically the monitor size of a S5 or iPhoneX or below. The first container involves a few nested rows and offset columns, so it isn't simple. The `media-featured-wrapper` container is overlapping the previous `homepage_header` container on mobile. If I remove the `media-featured-wrapper` container, the next element overlaps, so it is probably an issue with the first container I can't figure out. Any ideas would be appreciated. (This is on Modx, hence the square brackets) Thanks!

```
<div class=" container-fluid px-0 homepage_header border-bottom">
    <div class="row h-100 no-gutters">
        <div class="d-none d-lg-block col-md-4 homepage_header_left">
            <div class="col-md-9 offset-md-3 pt-4 text-center">
                <picture class="img-fluid">
                    <source srcset="[[++assets_url]]hp_logo_w_text.svg" type="image/svg+xml">
                    <source srcset="[[++assets_url]]hp_logo_w_text.png" type="image/png"> 
                    <img src="[[++assets_url]]hp_logo_w_text.png" class="img-fluid my-auto" alt="">
               </picture>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-12 col-lg-8 homepage_header_right">
            <div class="d-none d-lg-block">
                [[pdoMenu?
                    &startId=`0`
                    &level=`2`
                    &tplOuter=`HPNav.outerTpl`
                    &tplInner=`HPNav.innerTpl`
                    &tplParentRow=`HPNav.parentRowTpl`
                    &tplInnerRow=`HPNav.innerRowTpl`
                    &tpl=`HPNav.rowTpl`
                    &fullLink=`TRUE`
                    &excludeDocs=`1`
                ]]
            </div>
            <picture class="d-block d-lg-none img-fluid mt-0">
                <source srcset="[[++assets_url]]img/hp_mobile_logo.webp" type="image/webp">
                <source srcset="[[++assets_url]]img/hp_mobile_logo.png" type="image/png"> 
                <img src="[[++assets_url]]img/hp_mobile_logo.png" class="d-block d-lg-none img-fluid mt-0" alt="Activate Body Logo">
            </picture>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-9 col-md-10 offset-md-2 offset-lg-0">
                    <h2 class="g-highlight d-block d-lg-none">Text</h2>
                    <h2 class="highlight d-none d-lg-inline">Text</h2>
                    <h1 class="b_hp_header_text mb-5 mt-2">Text</h1>
                    <a href="#contact" class="btn btn-success btn-lg my-0 px-4 text-center" roll="button">TEXT!</a>
                 </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>   
</div>

<div class="container-fluid media-featured-wrapper border-bottom">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12 text-center">
            <span class="sr-only">As Featured In</span>
            <ul class="list-inline media_featured text-center mx-auto" role="list">
                <li class="list-inline-item img-fluid" role="listitem"><img src="[[++assets_url]]img1.png" class="img-fluid" alt=""></li>
                <li class="list-inline-item img-fluid" role="listitem"><img src="[[++assets_url]]img2.png" class="img-fluid" alt=""></li>
                <li class="list-inline-item img-fluid" role="listitem"><img src="[[++assets_url]]img3.png" class="img-fluid" alt=""></li>
            </ul>   
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Related CSS

```
.homepage_header {
  height: 640px;
  margin-bottom:0px;
}

.homepage_header_left {
    background-color: #005a8a;  
    background: rgba(0,112,168,1);
    background: -webkit-gradient(left top, right top, color-stop(0%, rgba(0,112,168,1)), color-stop(50%, rgba(0,99,148,1)), color-stop(100%, rgba(0,90,138,1)));
    background: -o-linear-gradient(left, rgba(0,112,168,1) 0%, rgba(0,99,148,1) 50%, rgba(0,90,138,1) 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, from(rgba(0,112,168,1)), color-stop(50%, rgba(0,99,148,1)), to(rgba(0,90,138,1)));
    background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(0,112,168,1) 0%, rgba(0,99,148,1) 50%, rgba(0,90,138,1) 100%);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#0070a8', endColorstr='#005a8a', GradientType=1 );   
    padding-top: 0px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    padding-right:20px!important;
    text-align: center;
    height: 100%;
}

.homepage_header_left img, .homepage_header_left picture {
    max-height: 585px;
}

.homepage_header_right {
    padding-top: 1rem;
    text-align: left;
    padding-right: 2rem!important;
    padding-left: 2rem!important;
    height: auto;
}
/* For Modernizer.js */
.no-webp .homepage_header_right {
    padding-top: 1rem;
    text-align: left;
    padding-right: 2rem!important;
    padding-left: 2rem!important;
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,0) 20%, rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%), url('../img/hp_gym_right.jpg');
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%,rgba(255,255,255) 20%,rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%), url('../img/hp_gym_right.jpg');
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom,  rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%,rgba(255,255,255) 20%,rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%), url('../img/hp_gym_right.jpg'); 
    background-size: cover;
}

.webp .homepage_header_right {
    padding-top: 1rem;
    text-align: left;
    padding-right: 2rem!important;
    padding-left: 2rem!important;
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,0) 20%, rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%), url('../img/hp_gym_right.webp');
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%,rgba(255,255,255) 20%,rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%), url('../img/hp_gym_right.webp');
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom,  rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%,rgba(255,255,255) 20%,rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%), url('../img/hp_gym_right.webp'); 
    background-size: cover;
}

.b_hp_header_text {
    font-family: 'Montserrat', arial, sans-serif;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 3.5rem;
    color: #000000;
    text-transform:capitalize;
}

/*--- FEATURED MEDIA ---*/
.media-featured-wrapper {
    margin-bottom:20px;
    height:auto;
}

.media_featured ul{
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: .5em 0;
    color: #bfbfbf;
    font-size: .63em;
    border-spacing: 3px;
    border-collapse: separate;
}
.media_featured li img {
    max-height: 30px;
    margin: 15px 15px 0px 15px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.media_featured ul li {
    max-width: 200px;

}
```

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of what is happening? might help us out a bit of what and how the container is overlapping

Comment: Most likely it has to do with the hard-coded `height: 630px`. Without a [mcve] your chances of getting help here are slim. Also note regardless of your preferred frontend language/framework, the browser is hit by HTML + CSS + JS. And that's exactly what you should provide as there are far more CSS/JS/HTML experts than Modx experts.

Comment: Sorry about that, the site is actually live, but was unsure if linking to it directly was good practice. The hard coded height WAS the issue, and has since been changes to min-height.

Answer (score 0):

It was the height property assigned to the homepage_header section, so I removed it entirely. It also needed a change to a lot of padding and margins, and to make the H1 text responsive. A lot of trial and error, too many tweaks to state here, and I have it working. Thanks!